# Urlwatch from command prompt on Windows

Tags: python, command-line, web-scraping

I'm having trouble starting urlwatch from Windows command-line after installing it successfully with pip3. It's not installed as .exe file in Python3x/scripts folder like other packages. 
Can it only be run from Linux terminal, or is it possible to use it from Windows command(and how)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but I just had the same issue – solved it by downloading the package (*.tar.gz) manually, extracting it and running "python urlwatch" inside it (after installing the dependencies as instructed here: https://github.com/thp/urlwatch).